# joomla in main folder and move the old webpages to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, dns, joomla1.7

I am planning to install Joomla in my webserver and as i don't want the old website be offline while i am working on joomla. After searhing, i found some possibilities, which i need your help to choose a final solution.

1 solution:  move the old site to a subfolder and install joomla in main folder. point the subfolder by changing .htaccess in main folder...
But there is another .htaccess file in joomla so will it be a problem?

2nd: change dns to another server(which i have) and make old website available there

could you please propose a better solution among these or another
thanks in advance

Comment: 3 option is to create a subdomain e.g. old.example.com. Create a separate vhost for this one. If the old site uses htaccess or uses absolute urls the old site would break if you use a subfolder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put Joomla in a subfolder. You don't have to do anything to the existing site while you build the Joomla site. When you are done, move the old site in to a sub folder and the entire Joomla install in to the root.

Joomla uses relative URLs so it will work where ever you put it. The only think you will have to mind is SEF URLs. When you have Joomla in a subfolder you have to change the Joomla root in HTACCESS when you have SEF URLs turned on. I generally just leave it off until the site goes live so you don't have to remember to change it.

Comment: Thanks Brent i didn't know that changing folders will not affect joomla installation.